# Setting the PATH in .profile works without exporting it, how?

Tags: bash, login

the default .profile does not export PATH, still the PATH set there is available to all processes.

How does that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is already an exported shell variable, then subsequent resetting of the variable will automatically export it.  So in this case, if you run "env" prior to where .profile sets PATH, you will probably see it was previously set / exported (either in /etc/profile, /etc/bash_profile, or somewhere else).

Comment: it looks like login initially sets PATH
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/login.1.html
making it implicitly exported, then pam_env.so (loaded by login, I think) resets it based on /etc/environment